# My PNG image looks too small when i put it on the screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview, photoshop, iphone-4, retina-display

i have a PNG picture (640*960), when i place it on my app screen (using an UIImageView) it looks too small (very very small), i didn't even know what does its dimensions became, can you please help me figure out why i got that? thanx in advance :)

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Do you create UIImageView programmatically? If yes, please, post your code

Comment: Actually no, i use directly the UIImageView in the interface Builder

Comment: And you're sure that your imageview's dimensions are correct?

Comment: my PNG picture dimensions is 640*960, concerning the UIImageView, i didn't touch its paramters, i only maked sure that the UIImageView does fill all bounds of the UIView, then, i have imported the PNG from my Resources folder into the image property, please have a look on my EDIT, thanx :)

Comment: On the Size Inspector, it's width and height are seen as 320 and 480, right? And does it look OK when you specify the image from the interface builder? I mean can you see that it fills your image view on design time?

Comment: OK, on the size inspector of the UIImageView, i have maked it 640*960 in the place of 320*480, the result has improved, but i still have the image which is smaller than the screen bounds. i use to work with Xcode 3.2, i hadn't that issue, since i moved the Xcode4 i begin to have many difficulties, i doubt that it has something dealing with the Retina display of the iPhone4.

Comment: @Malloc Could you post a screenshot of what the image looks like on-screen?

Answer (score -1):

There's an API for creating an UIImage with a scale.

```
NSData *imageData = ...;
UIImage *unscaled = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:unscaled.CGImage
                                   scale:2
                             orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

You may or may not want to use `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` as well, to dynamically detect scale/retina.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer, however i didn't intend to put the image programmatically, i use directly the UIImageView in the IB.